# Angular Material Mat-Select Width Based on Longest Option Width

Tags: css, angular, sass, width, angular-material2

I have a mat-select with options, I am looking to set this inline to text and have the drop down only be as long as the longest option. I can probably do some hackery with js / css vanilla style, but looking for a better solution. any thoughts?

```html
<mat-select
  [ngClass]="{'missing-selection': !SelectedOption}"
    [(value)]="SelectedOption"
    id="select"
    (selectionChange)="optionChange($event)"
  >
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let option of data.Options"
      [value]="option.Value"
      >{{ option.Label}}</mat-option
    >
  </mat-select>
```

Comment: That's where you're wrong : selects in Angular material aren't real select, they're components that are dynamically placed by the CDK through an overlay service. If you want to adapt your input size to your list size, you will have to create the exact same component, and measure it. This means that you have to either make hard calculations before displaying it, or change the size of the input after the list is displayed.

Comment: Yea, I kind of figured that, was hoping there was an out of box or already made solution I was missing. I'll post what I come up with after I try a few more things out.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/7627#issuecomment-505646063 is a good workaround

Answer (score 11):

Please, try this (for selected option)...

```
.auto-width{
    .mat-form-field {
        width: auto !important;
    }
    .mat-select-value {
        max-width: 100%;
        width: auto;
    }  
}

<div class="auto-width">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select>
        <mat-option value="long">Long description</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="foo">Foo</mat-option>      
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: @nicolas.leblanc i got it working by adding `::ng-deep` to the outer selector

Comment: It does not look great though... the dropdown arrow is all the on the left when no value is selected, and just to the right of the text when one is selected (not in the far right). When a long description is selected, all the text is visible, but the line along the bottom of the control does not extend to match it.

Comment: May be I'm late to the party, but, it might help someone, replace width:auto with min-width: 100%, that moves the dropdown arrow to the right side.
`.mat-select-value {       max-width: 100%;       min-width: 100%; }`

Answer (score 2):

For Angular 16 or higher you can use `panelWidth=""` see docs. https://material.angular.io/components/select/api

Answer (score 1):

For `"@angular/material": "13.3.2"` this works for me

```
  ::ng-deep .mat-select-value {
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
  }
  ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-infix {
    width: auto !important;
    min-width: 180px !important;
    padding-right: 13px !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution for Angular Material v17 using `panelClass`.

```html
   <mat-select panelClass="custom-class">
```

To match the width of the `mat-select`, angular-material sets the width in the style attribute of the `.cdk-overlay-panel` element. Angular-material also puts the panel class on the child element of `.cdk-overlay-panel`, so both a `:has(>...)` and a `!important` are required to override the panel width.

```css
.cdk-overlay-pane:has(>.custom-class){
   width: initial !impontant;
}
```

My specific use case just needed the sizing to get bigger, so I used:

```css
.cdk-overlay-pane:has(>.custom-class){
   min-width: fit-content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using:

```
::ng-deep .mat-autocomplete-panel {
  min-width: fit-content !important;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this code, it works but it is not dynamic.

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field {
  width: 50px !important;
}
::ng-deep .mat-label {
    width: 50px !important;
}
::ng-deep .mat-select {
    width: 50px !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-option {
    width: 50px !important;
}
```