# Material select remove empty space

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular-material

What is the best approach to remove empty space Material select/input?
What I mean is to have the width of the field same size as content.

[image]
https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
.auto-width{
    .mat-form-field {
        width: auto !important;
    }
    .mat-select-value {
        max-width: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
    }  
}
```

and on your html content:

```
<div class="auto-width">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select>
        <mat-option value="long">Long description</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="foo">Foo</mat-option>      
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

from this [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54518083/angular-material-mat-select-width-based-on-longest-option-width)